Write text if 3 criteria is met VBA
I'm wondering if I could write "text" in column D if this criteria are met:

Column A is not null
Column B contains "yes"
Column C is not null

These are my current idea for the criteria. But, I have no idea of how to do the rests.
Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("B2:AG" & lastRowSourceSheet).AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("B2:AG" & lastRowSourceSheet).AutoFilter field:=29, Criteria1:="TIDAK DISARANKAN"
Sheets(sourceSheet).Range("B2:AG" & lastRowSourceSheet).AutoFilter field:=31, Criteria1:="<>"

Please create the code in dynamic way because I have thousands of data rows. Any suggestion of how I could write the code is appreciated.
I hope it make sense. Thank you so much!

You don't need VBA for this - just use a formula.

What do you want to write in column D, and like Ike said, a formula will do. Unless you want to practive VBA, but then I'd try/search harder first.

you literally want it to write "text"?

I will write something else, but for example "text" is appropriate. I wish to create it in VBA so it become automatic because I will integrate that code to the other code. Hence, in one run button, VBA will do all the work. Thank you so much @Excellor

Sub test()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = 7 'you need to calculate this depending on your dataset

For i = 1 To LastRow 'from row 1 to 7
    If Len(Range("A" & i).Value) > 0 _
    And Len(Range("C" & i).Value) > 0 _
    And InStr(1, Range("B" & i).Value, "yes") > 0 Then
        Range("D" & i).Value = "some text"
    End If
Next i

End Sub



It looks like that in  your example image row 4 and 7 are doing it wrong (to what I understood of what OP wanted), however, if I test it on my worksheet it works as inteded; besides that I used LastRow = Cells(rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, (found elsewhere) to find the last row within the B column.

@Excellor Updated my code because it was not fitting the image. I Understood criteria is that cell A and C must not be blank and B must contai the string "yes"

@FoxfireAndBurnAndBurns you're correct! I misread it so that A and C should be empty, but indeed, they should not be empty, so your image (and code) are now correct indeed.

I've tried the code but it doesnt give any results. I added Dim wb and ws to direct it to sheet4 and change lastrow = ws.Cells(rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

@littleturtle I don't know exactly how you are implementing the code but it works perfectly. Make sure you are referencing all ranges and worksheets properly. If it does not work you can open a new question, post the code, data example and expected output.

Ok, an answer is accepted, but I would like to give you two formulae anyway:
Case sensitive: (based on FIND())
=IF(AND(LEN(A1) <> 0;NOT(ISERROR(FIND("yes";B1)));LEN(C1) <> 0);"text";"<Booo>")

Case insensitive: (based on SEARCH())
=IF(AND(LEN(A1) <> 0;NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("yes";B1)));LEN(C1) <> 0);"text";"<Booo>")

Hereby a screenshot of what is looks like:

As far as the speed is concerned: I have filled my entire Excel worksheet (1,048,576 rows) and populating and calculating both formulae for the entire worksheet took less than ten seconds.
So why go for a VBA approach?

a formula approach forces all cells to have a value, even something like ="". VBA approach can skip cells and leave it absolutely empty (empty is not the same than "". This is the only reason I can think about why VBA approach
